# python selenium proxys in chrome/phantomjs

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-chrome, python-3.x, selenium

I've tried to use proxy s in chrome but, 
I get this error.

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(proxy=proxy)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxy'
```

This is the code I am trying to use
but it only works with FireFox, so I was wondering if it is possible to do this with phatom JS and chrome

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
from selenium import webdriver
myProxy = "31.28.244.230:41905"

proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': myProxy,
    'ftpProxy': myProxy,
    'sslProxy': myProxy,
    'noProxy': '' # set this value as desired
    })

driver = webdriver.Chrome(proxy=proxy)

driver.get("http://ipchicken.com/")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it like this

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "23.23.23.23:3128" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % PROXY)

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
PROXY = "31.28.244.230:41905"

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy']={
"httpProxy":PROXY,
"ftpProxy":PROXY,
"sslProxy":PROXY,
"noProxy":None,
"proxyType":"MANUAL",
"autodetect":False
     }

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.whatsmyip.org/')
```